# Embedding Google Maps in a codepen

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I was hoping to make an example of Google Maps embedding using codepen. It doesn't work properly. Here's the [codepen](http://codepen.io/jonnybarnes/pen/bfdLj).

The map loads centred in the correct place but its a static image, not an interactive map with a marker and info box attached.

Is this a limitation with how codepen handles javascript or is there a way of making this work?

Comment: I actually emailed their help desk about this very issue. They said it was a known bug and are still working on it.

Comment: You can use [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) though, it works quite flawlessly

Comment: Whilst it doesn't work on the codepen website itself, if you embed the codepen on your own website everything works as you would expect.

Comment: If you open console, you will see message: `Uncaught ReferenceError: F is not defined`.

Answer (score 2):

founder of CodePen here.  We've recently fixed this issue and the pen in question loads without problems.  Thanks for your patience.